# CentOS 7 DVD ISO vs Everything ISO different

Tags: centos, centos-7

What is different between CentOS 7 **DVD ISO** and **Everything ISO** in http://centos.org/download/ ?

CentOS 7 DVD ISO 3.86 GB

Everything ISO 6.58 GB